# Cast an object in a control to a class in its parent control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to access a member of a parent control of my current control.

Here is the parent:

```
public partial class Controls_MyPanel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private String _strSubTitle = String.Empty;

    public String SubTitle
    {
        get { return _strSubTitle; }
        set
        {
            _strSubTitle = value;
            lblSubTitle.Text = _strSubTitle;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the child control:

```
public partial class Controls_MyChild : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    function ChangeSubTitle
    {
        ((Controls_MyPanel)Parent.Parent).SubTitle = "Foo";
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to get the defintion of Controls_MyPanel into Controls_MyChild. I can't use `using` because I don't have a namespace. I tried adding something like:

```
<%@ Register src="MyPanel.ascx" tagname="MyPanel" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

to the markup for `MyChild`, but of course that's circular, since `MyChild` is already registered on `MyPanel`.

Comment: You should have access to it already. They are -- unless you defined them in different namespaces -- in the same namespace. What error are you getting?

Comment: It's just saying `The type or namespace name 'Controls_MyPanel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: They are in the same project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you created a website project (with ASP.net) instead of a pure ASP.net application.

```
File->New->Web Sites...
```

instead of

```
File->New->Project...->Visual C#->Web->ASP.NET Web Application
```

In Web Site project, the code behind file is compiled dynamically when page is loaded.  They're isolated so you cannot reference the name of the class unless you Register in the aspx/ascx file, which in your case would create circular dependency.

To solve the problem, if you don't want to change project type, you can use interface.

1. Right click the web site project, Add->Add New Item...
2. Select "Class".  Visual Studio will prompt you if you want to place the file in App_Code.  Yes.
3. In the generated file, change `public class ClassName` to `public interface ISomeInterface`.  Then define a property like `String SubTitle {get; set;}`
4. Implement the interface in your parent control.
5. In your child control, cast the `Parent.Parent` to `ISomeInterface`

Then you can access the `SubTitle` property via the `ISomeInterface` interface.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something different where I got the Label directly with a `FindControl` call, but this answer could still be useful for others in the same spot.